# Download csv file with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv, download

I'm trying to download a csv file programmatically through python and selenium because I need to do this hundreds of times.  The manual steps to do the work are:

1. go to https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced
2. Select County Name in drop down, enter "IOWA" in the text box, and click Add
3. Select Doc Number in drop down, enter "358407" in the text box, and click Add
4. Click Submit
5. Select first row of resulting table (opens new page in same tab)
6. Highlight CSV Report on right side
7. Click Go to save the file.

I have everything working programmatically through Step 5, and I believe step 6 (box2... below) works as well.  However when I run the submit2 line in the code, nothing seems to download.  I'm assuming this is probably an easy catch/fix for those of you that know selenium far better than I.  I've also tried

```
source = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'DTLNavigator_Report2_ReportsListBox')
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.double_click(source)
```

but it didn't seem to work either.  So I'm either messing something up with the code or I just can't seem to find the downloaded file.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I hope I've included enough information for you to follow.

Below is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": r"D://Users//User//Downloads","download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True, "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
DRIVER_PATH = "C://temp/webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/Search/Disclaimer.aspx?FromUrl=../search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)
driver.get("https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#btAgree"))).click()
box = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sCriteria"))))
box.select_by_index(4)
iE = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtCrit")
iE.send_keys('IOWA')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#btAdd"))).click()
box = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sCriteria"))))
box.select_by_index(3)
iE = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtCrit")
iE.send_keys('358407')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#btAdd"))).click()                                  
submit = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btSearch").click()
myTable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'SearchResults')
dataSelect = myTable.click()

box2 = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#DTLNavigator_Report2_ReportsListBox"))))
box2.select_by_value('CSVMailingList')

submit2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ReportListButton").click()
```

Comment: So I was able to get the above code to work when options.headless = False but not when options.headless = True.  The csv file never appears in the downloads folder.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to download files in headless mode is to specify the download path using the `driver.command_executor` method.

I was able to download the csv in the current directory using the following code in headless mode-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import time

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

DRIVER_PATH = "C://temp/webscraping/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
#set download path (set to current working directory in this example)
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow','downloadPath':os.getcwd()}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

driver.get("https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/Search/Disclaimer.aspx?FromUrl=../search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)
driver.get("https://propertyinfo.revenue.wi.gov/WisconsinProd/search/advancedsearch.aspx?mode=advanced")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#btAgree"))).click()
box = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sCriteria"))))
box.select_by_index(4)
iE = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtCrit")
iE.send_keys('IOWA')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#btAdd"))).click()
box = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sCriteria"))))
box.select_by_index(3)
iE = driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtCrit")
iE.send_keys('358407')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#btAdd"))).click()                                  
submit = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btSearch").click()
myTable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'SearchResults')
dataSelect = myTable.click()

box2 = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#DTLNavigator_Report2_ReportsListBox"))))
box2.select_by_value('CSVMailingList')

submit2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ReportListButton").click()

# wait for csv download to complete
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you Kamalesh your solution worked perfectly!  Those three lines (driver.command to command_result) were all that I was missing!

Comment: You're welcome :))